# How to send data from API to Android

Tags: android, laravel

I'm developing a Transport Management System using Dingo API with Laravel and Retrofit for Mobile App. When the clerk approves the request, the notification should be send to who uses android app(Client),So i wanna send data from Server to App.What are the possible ways to do it ?

**Updated**

How to use brozot/laravel-firebase cloud messaging ? Can anyone give an example for that ?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: push notification using this you can archive you want

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Thanks! I will try these and post if i succeed :)

Comment: ok..///////////

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

1. Use push notification system like.
   This approach is supported by Google. But is delayed to inform like what you are doing is right. Work that is not suitable for real-time. And does not require you to have a server and a lot of code to write.

   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client
      Or
   https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ -> move to firebase upper link
2. Use signalR 
   This real-time but connections are not loose management.And a lot of coding.

   https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/SignalRAndroid

Comment: I will try :) Thanks!